# Como pegar o response de um GET http usando HttpURLConnection java.net?

Tags: java, rest

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
package com.akamai.edgegrid.auth;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class C {

   public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "akab-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.luna.akamaiapis.net");
      conn.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "EG1-HMAC-SHA256 client_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;timestamp=20160714T19:25:00+0000;nonce=8b97e62f-e5d6-4a57-8f64-db423f24b7ee;signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));     
      String line;
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
       result.append(line);
      }
      rd.close();
      return result.toString();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
     System.out.println(getHTML("https://akab-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.luna.akamaiapis.net/alerts/v1/portal-user?status=active"));
   }
}
```

Eu tomo de volta um:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.luna.akamaiapis.net/papi/v0/contracts
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.akamai.edgegrid.auth.C.getHTML(C.java:17)
at com.akamai.edgegrid.auth.C.main(C.java:28)
```

Mas eu queria ver o cabeçalho de volta ex:

```
{
  "type": "https://problems./-/pep-authn/request-error",
  "title": "Bad request",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Error message is here",
  "instance": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.luna.akamaiapis.net/papi/v0/contracts",
  "method": "GET",
  "serverIp": "23.45.226.189",
  "clientIp": "200.220.180.109",
  "requestId": "34799682",
  "requestTime": "2016-07-14T19:32:10Z"
}
```

eu só tenho o código http de falha... há anos não mexo com java...estou apanhando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem você está querendo ver os cabeçalhos da resposta da sua requisição.

Para isso use métodos `HttpURLConnection.getHeader...()`, como por exemplo `getHeaderFields()`, que retorna o mapa de chaves e valores do cabeçalho, ou então `getHeaderFieldKey(String name)`, que retorna o valor da chave `name`.

Para iterar pelo mapa:

```
Map<String, List<String>> responseMap = connection.getHeaderFields();
for (String chave : responseMap.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(chave + " = ");

    List<String> valores = responseMap.get(chave);
    for (int i = 0; i < valores.size(); i++) {
        String valor = valores.get(i);
        System.out.println(valor + ", ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Piovezan!
 Ele me retornou o seguinte.
 null = 
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized, 
WWW-Authenticate = 
EG1-HMAC-SHA256 realm="akab-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.luna.akamaiapis.net", 
Date = 
Thu, 14 Jul 2016 20:11:11 GMT, 
Content-Length = 
413, 
Content-Type = 
application/problem+json, 
Connection = 
close,

Preciso autenticar dessa forma https://developer.akamai.com/introduction/Client_Auth.html

Comment: Ah tá, achei que fosse só saber o que vem na resposta. Depois vejo com calma o que pode ser. 401 Unauthorized quer dizer que a autenticação falhou, talvez seja um problema na maneira que o seu cabeçalho de autenticação está sendo montado.

Comment: Não tenho pistas. O cabeçalho Authorization da requisição parece ok, a minha única suspeita é que o timestamp precise ser bem preciso por exigência da API de autenticação. Apesar da requisição exigir UTC e a resposta trazer GMT, tente comparar o timestamp das duas para ver se está dentro de um intervalo suficientemente pequeno.

Comment: É entao...antes era o timestamp, tem um delay de 30 segundos, mas antes quando era timestamp voltava 400 nao 401, eu saquei o é porém ainda estou longe de resolver, a akamai tem um algoritmo de criptografia, eu preciso aplicar a criptografia na minha chave antes de passar

Comment: Provavelmente é isso mesmo. Se encontrar problemas aplicando a criptografia abra uma nova pergunta, pois aí vai ser um assunto bem diferente da que foi feita aqui.